# Где скачать образ Debian 5 Lenny?

Tags: debian, linux

Где можно скачать образ без всяких GUI и т.д., чтобы просто загрузил и сразу вводишь пароль рута! Лучше образ для virtual box.

Ссылочку пожалуйста! :)

Comment: Так Вам что надо: диск для установки или уже готовый livecd?

Comment: Лучше и то и другое.

Comment: Установочный диск скачайте с официального сайта. Других нет. livecd готовых официальных нет, а неофициальные — на свой страх и риск.

Comment: С такими запросами (дайте готовое, чтобы сразу заработало), может, Вам лучше windows livecd дать?

Comment: Нет, спасибо, виндовс не надо. А ссылочку на официальный образ можно?

Comment: На официальный установочный образ? Вы чё, прикалываетесь, что ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы впервые сталкиваетесь с Debian, то самое правильное - это зайти к ним на сайт. По [ссылке](http://debian.org/distrib/) вы увидете множество опций загрузки. Если нет графической оболочки, то, видимо, нужен серверный вариант. Да, для VirtualBox подойдет точно такой же образ, который ставится на реальный сервер.

Comment: Какой образ нужно скачать для 64 bit процессора?

Comment: Нужно перейти по ссылке загрузки через интернет и там будут варианты для разных архитектур, в том числе и под amd64.

Answer (score 2):

По [ссылке](http://debian.org/distrib/netinst) можно закачать образ amd64. А еще можно качать с [зеркала](http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian/) Яндекса - если у вас локальный Яндекс будет быстро. В корне зеркала лежит README, которое поясняет назначение папок.

Answer (score 0):

Понятия не имею, зачем требуется такая древняя версия debian. В debian 8 вполне можно не устанавливать DE, а просто поставить голую консоль.

Comment: Дату вопроса пробовали глянуть?)

Comment: lel... Что оно у меня делает в новых вопросах?

Comment: Дух сообщества некробампит зачем-то)